How to save information from an async request and use it in another async request after an event is triggered?
Part of a game I am making requires a query to gpt-4o asking whether two people have met. An inital person is provided and the user has to input the name of someone who they think has met the initial person. After the guess is submitted through an input field, a promise containing the text "true" or "false" is returned.
Depending on the response, I need to update some values contained in "gameState" and pass them into another query to gpt-4o.
However, since the response is a promise, I cannot update global variables using the response. As of now, "gameState" is initialized inside the async function. "gameState" is changed when the function is run, but when I input a different name it resets and "count" does not increase.
How do I use the information from the promise to update variables, wait until another input is submitted, then pass those updated variables along with the new input into another query?
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';


const { OpenAI } = require('openai');
const openai = new OpenAI({ apiKey: '[myKey}');



function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef();

 let people = ["Donald Trump", "Taylor Swift"];

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    play(inputRef.current.value, people[0], people[1]);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

 async function play(guess, p1, p2) {
  let gameState = {
    currentPerson: p1,
    count: 0
   
  }
    const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
      messages: [
        { 
          role: "system",
          content: "respond with true or false in lower case depening on if these people have met" 
        },
        {
          role: "user",
          content: `${gameState.currentPerson}, ${guess}`
        
        },
        
      ],
        model: "gpt-4o",
    }); 

    if(completion.choices[0].message.content === "true" && guess === p2) {
      console.log("You Win!");
      gameState.count++;
      console.log(gameState);

    } else if(completion.choices[0].message.content === "true") {
      console.log("Correct");
      gameState.count++;
      gameState.currentPerson = guess;
      console.log(gameState);

    } else {
      console.log("Wrong");

    }
    
  }

  return ( 
    
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
      <label >
        Name:
        <input name="guessInput" type="text" ref={inputRef} />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>

    
  );
}

export default App;

I have tried changing the input event handler into an async function and making the API call there but it resulted in an error.

Adding regular variable isn't enough as indicated in the official React docs

Local variables don’t persist between renders. When React renders this component a second time, it renders it from scratch—it doesn’t consider any changes to the local variables.

Possible solution

Use React's useState hook to manage the game state.

Move the API call and game logic into a separate function.

Update the state using the setState function provided by useState.


In the play function, we use setGameState to update the state based on the API response:
setGameState(prevState => {
  let newState = { ...prevState };
  // Update newState based on the result
  return newState;
});

Modified solution
import './App.css';
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

const { OpenAI } = require('openai');
const openai = new OpenAI({ apiKey: '[myKey]' });

function App() {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const [gameState, setGameState] = useState({
    currentPerson: "Donald Trump",
    count: 0
  });

  const people = ["Donald Trump", "Taylor Swift"];

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const guess = inputRef.current.value;
    await play(guess, gameState.currentPerson, people[1]);
  }

  async function play(guess, currentPerson, finalPerson) {
    try {
      const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
        messages: [
          { 
            role: "system",
            content: "respond with true or false in lower case depending on if these people have met" 
          },
          {
            role: "user",
            content: `${currentPerson}, ${guess}`
          },
        ],
        model: "gpt-4",
      }); 

      const result = completion.choices[0].message.content;

      setGameState(prevState => {
        let newState = { ...prevState };

        if (result === "true" && guess === finalPerson) {
          console.log("You Win!");
          newState.count++;
        } else if (result === "true") {
          console.log("Correct");
          newState.count++;
          newState.currentPerson = guess;
        } else {
          console.log("Wrong");
        }

        console.log(newState);
        return newState;
      });

    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error calling OpenAI API:", error);
    }
  }

  return ( 
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
      <label>
        Name:
        <input name="guessInput" type="text" ref={inputRef} />
      </label>
      <button type="submit">
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default App;

Useful references
https://react.dev/learn/state-a-components-memory#adding-a-state-variable
